# Brute force attack using burp suite

Tags: security, brute-force, burp

I am trying to perform a brute force attack using Burp Suite on a login page on my localhost and it is giving me a status code 200 for each value it is checking or sometimes it is giving me a status code 411 for each value. This includes the correct value for the username and password as well what do I do? how do I get status code 200 for the correct username and password only?

[This is a screenshot of what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdkio.jpg)

I have tried every possible different attack type from sniper to cluster bomb but it is still showing the same thing. I am trying to find a solution to my problem